PowerApps have data table values change color if they changed
In my Powerapps I have a data table of the original data. The user will choose some drop down options and the inputs are patched to a collection of the table with the updated values. I’m trying to figure out how I can make the values in the updated table (collection after inputs) red if they went down or green if they went up. I need Powerapps to look at the original table and then look at the updated and apply the color conditional formatting. Thanks for the assistance!

I assume that you are storing your original data with the ID in the collection. You can use the rectangle background in the gallery and lookup the original Data with the ID and compare the value with the current row value to decide the color.
